# Data structure for efficient multi-parameters search

Tags: sql, data-structures

I have collection of multidimensional object (e.g `class Person = {age : int , height : int, weight : int etc...}`).
I need to query the collection with queries where some dimensions are fixed and the rest unspecified  (e.g `getallPersonWith {age = c , height = a}` or `getAllPersonWith {weigth = d}`...)

Right now i have a multimap with `{age, Height,...}` (e.g all dimension that can be fixed) -> `List : Person`.To perform a query i first compute the set of keys that verify the query, then merge the corresponding list from the map.
Is there anything better, in terms of query speed ? in particular is there anything closer to using one sorted list by dimension (which i believe to be the fastest solutions, but too cumbersome to manage:) )

Just to be clear, i am not looking for an sql query.

Comment: Do you have any particular sql table structure in mind yet or just shooting in the dark for now?

Comment: i can't use sql, those are in memory temporary object.I wanted something light weight and simple

Comment: What programing languate are you using? C++?

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://code.google.com/p/cqengine/ ?

Comment: @Jester thanks , why dont you give an answer so i can up vote you :)

Comment: you are wellcome. and Answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purpose you can have a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/cqengine/

Should get you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM person p
WHERE gender = 'F'
  AND age >=18
  AND age < 30
  AND weight > 60 -- metric measures here !!
  AND weight < 70
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * from couple c
    WHERE c.one = p.id OR c.two=p.id
    );
```

Why do you think I use SQL?

Comment: for the subquery one column should be better in terms of preformance:

  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ID from couple
    WHERE c.one = p.id OR c.two=p.id
    );

Comment: Nonsense. The query optimiser will see that only a boolean value is wanted, since none of the '*' will be referenced by the outer query.

Comment: Just thinking of does all DBMS has query optimisers working this way

Comment: Wrt query-optimisers: the smart ones do, the idiots dont. This is an implementation dependent isssue. := depending on the implementation, One could also try: `select 1`, or `select True` , maybe the implementation will undesrtand it. Anything goes...